# excel match formula with range

Tags: excel, range, match

A have problem with excel 2010 and formula using multiple values check:

```
   A       B      C
1 Test1   Test2 Test3
2 Name1   XXX    xxx
3 Name1   YYY   yyy
4 Name2   VVV    vvv
5 Name3   BBB    bbb
6   
7 Test1   Name1 
8 Test2  XXX    
9 Test3  #VALUE!  <--- formula =MATCH(1,(B7=A2:A5)*(B8=B2:B5), 0)
```

I always have the same error. I debuged it and the evaluation of 'A2:A5' generate error `#VALUE!`
but when I select this and press F9 it expand to `{"Name1";"Name1";"Name2";"Name3"}`

Any ideas where can be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is an "array formula" so you need to confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>  so that you get curly braces like { and } around the formula

alternatively you can add an `INDEX` function which means it can be entered as a regular formula, i.e.

`=MATCH(1,INDEX((B7=A2:A5)*(B8=B2:B5),0),0)`

Comment: Thank you. Online tutorials forget to metion this 'C+S+E' magic.